# Retrieve data from text field

Tags: objective-c

I have a text field in my app. I am trying to store whatever is entered into the text field in an array and display it in my root view controller (which is a table view) on click of a button.

The method for the button is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)addNewCountry:(id)sender
{

    [rootViewController.details addObject:nameField.text];
    NSLog(@"Country name is %@", rootViewController.details);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
    [rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"new country added");
}
```

details is the array declared in RootViewController

However, the text field text is not retrieved. Can anybody tell me what am i missing?

Comment: if you  are agree with the answer press the tick mark

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it as a new question, don't edit the old one. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cont directly insert your string data to your array, you need to store as a string

```
NSString *stringval = [NSString stringWithString: nameField.text];
```

then add it in to your string using addobject

```
[rootViewController.details addObject: stringcal];
```

Comment: found out the problem. text field was not linked in IB. sorry for bothring for such a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
[rootViewController.details addObject:nameField.text];
```

to this

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithString: nameField.text];
[rootViewController.details addObject: name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your details array declared as NSMutableArray?  It must be declared as an NSMutableArray in order for it to be modifiable. Also when you initialized the array did you add this after the allocation:

`[details retain];`